# Escape newlines when breaking text

Tags: insert-mode, wrap

I'm using Vim to typeset some Latex documents, and resizing it to take up half my screen so I can reference other materials on the other half. Therefore, `formatoptions+=t` would be very helpful here. Unfortunately, Latex would need the newlines produced by `textwidth` to be escaped with backslashes.

A quick scan through the options page shows no simple way to change `textwidth` wrapping to insert characters other than newlines, although the documentation for `wrapmargin` does mention that the `<EOL>` character is inserted.

Is it possible to change the `<EOL>` character in this case? Or to use some other method to escape these inserted newlines?

Comment: `Latex would need the newlines produced by textwidth to be escaped` Why??? Normally TeX doesn't differ (single) newline from space.

Comment: So today I just found out I'm stupid.

But okay, for a language like Python, how would we go about escaping newlines?

Comment: Don't use auto-format for Python. It's not intended for programming languages.

Comment: You can use `setlocal wrap` if you want long lines **to look** as if they were wrapped.

Comment: My issue is in navigating between lines: it's just annoying when `j` and `k` bring you up and down several visual lines.

Comment: So it's classical "XY" problem. Just use `gj` and `gk`, or, perhaps, `nnoremap j gj` and `nnoremap k gk`

Comment: Oh wow, okay this pretty much does the trick. Thanks so much Matt!